# Repeated invocations of Twitter Search API getting stalled after a couple of times

Tags: java, json, twitter

I am using Twitter Search API to get count of tweets on a given search string. Since API returns only number of tweets specified by 'count' parameter in the URL, I have to send REST call to the URL multiple  times.

I parse the JSON response returned after first call and get the ID of the last tweet and send that as 'max_id' in the URL next time to get more tweets.

Here is the code:

```
private static void sendSearchRequest(String token, String maxId) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Entering sendSearchRequest");
    byte[] temp = Base64.encodeBase64(token.getBytes());
    String url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23SearchString&count=100&include_entities=false";

    //Will be null in first invocation, not null in subsequent calls
    if(maxId != null)
        url += "&max_id="+maxId;

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    //Resend the request till response is not blank.
    if(response.toString().length() > 0){
        maxId = parseResponse(response.toString());
        System.out.println(positiveCount);
        sendSearchRequest(token, maxId);
    }else{
        System.out.println("No more results");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Exiting parseResponse");
}

private static String parseResponse(String response) {
    System.out.println("Entering parseResponse");
    String lastId = "";
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object object = parser.parse(response);
        JSONObject array = (JSONObject)object;
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)array.get("statuses");
        int size = jsonArray.size();
        positiveCount += size;
        System.out.println(size);

        //Find the index of last object in the array returned by API
        JSONObject lastObject = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(size-1);             

        //Get Tweet ID to be set as Max_id in next call to Twitter.
        Long id = (Long)lastObject.get("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        lastId = id+"";
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting parseResponse");
    return lastId;

}
```

The problem I am facing is that this code makes calls only couple of times. After that the call is not sent and program just hangs. I suspected it could be due to stale open connection, so I closed that manually but even that is not working.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Maybe it's the api that is restricting you. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

Comment: I am not even making those many requests :(

Comment: Got the issue. It is some kind of bug/restriction in Twitter API. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/34598 I made slight change to above code and put in a Thread.sleep(20000) before sending calls to Twitter API and it works fine. Terribly slow though :(

Comment: Can't be helped I guess. Glad you found a solution. Post that as answer and mark it, so the topic can be considered solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue. It is some kind of bug/restriction in Twitter API. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/34598 I made slight change to above code and put in a Thread.sleep(20000) before sending calls to Twitter API and it works fine. Terribly slow though :(

Comment: I have posted entire working code here: http://opreview.blogspot.in/2014/09/using-twitter-search-api-in-java.html